# Ubuntu 13.04 does not boot after update

Tags: boot, 13.04, updates, kernel, cryptsetup

as a complete newbie to Linux, I just installed a brand new Lenovo ThinkPad X230 with Ubuntu 13.04 from USB stick. Downloaded the installer from ubuntu.com and put it on a stick. No issues. Next day (this is: yesterday), the system offered update, including a new kernel. I did the update and now booting stalls with a violet screen saying

```
cryptsetup: evms_activate is not available
```

Pressing ESC, I see in the text display

```
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
No volume groups found
No volume groups found
```

In GRUB, I see two kernels offered, one 3.8.0-19-generic and one for recovery. The normal kernel behaves as said and the recovery kernel gives me long text log of the boot process, ending with

```
cryptsetup: evms_activate is not available
Begin: Waiting for encrypted source device  [   2.512095] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=02d2
```

(the USB device turns out to be the webcam). After quite some time, the waiting for the device seems to and and it enters a built-in shell I have no clue what to do with.

I have been advised to re-install, and I would happily do this when I had some indication that the issue won't happen again next time. Until then I would prefer to learn how to deal with such situations and rescue w/o new install...

Any ideas?

Comment: While installing, did you choose to encrypt anything? My suggestion, because you say you're new to Linux, is to re-install but **not** encrypt anything. Then, once you feel confident, give encryption a go.

Comment: Yes. I was encrypting the disk completely. Issue was resolved by a re-install from scratch, also with full encryption.