# Encrypted home dir: Cannot login after sudo password reset

Tags: 14.04, login, password, ecryptfs

I have a user, say *secretuser*, with an encrypted home directory. Unfortunately I forgot the password for user *secretuser*, because it was very secret. So I loggged on with another admin user, say *masteruser*, and changed the password for *secretuser* via graphical UI to, say, 'newpass'. When trying to login as *secretuser*, there was no "wrong password" or so when I use 'newpass', but I am sent back to the graphical logon screen immediately after some flash of the screen. So I logged on again as *masteruser* and did in a shell window:

```
masteruser$ su secretuser
```

I entered 'newpass' at the prompt and was able to log on to a shell. But still graphical login was not possible. Same effect as before. So I concluded that the graphical dialog does not do it's job completely and gave the command prompt a chance:

```
masteruser$ sudo passwd secretuser
```

Of course, I had to change to something else, say 'newpass1'. Unfortunately, the graphical login shows the same issue as before, but now, when I `su`'ed to *secretuser*, I only saw an encrypted file system.

```
masteruser@zhadum:~$ su secretuser
Passwort: newpass1
Signature not found in user keyring
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'
secretuser@zhadum:/home/masteruser$ cd /home/secretuser
secretuser@zhadum:~$ ls
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt
secretuser@zhadum:~$
```

Maybe I took security a bit too far, because now I am completely stuck. Seemingly the password is changed, but it does not work for the graphical login and also not for the decryption of the user's directory. Trying `ecryptfs-mount-private` as suggested did not work either, because neither 'newpass' nor 'newpass1' were accepted. Dropping and recreating the user would lose me 3 weeks of work because the most recent backup, shame on me, is not too current.

Do I have a chance to get access again?

**Update**: Thanks to the link given by @mxdsp I tried:

```
masteruser@zhadum:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
[sudo] password for masteruser: ---- 
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/secretuser/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: newpass1
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
masteruser@zhadum:~$ cd /var/log
masteruser@zhadum:/var/log$ tail syslog
Oct  9 06:05:19 zhadum ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Incorrect wrapping key for file [/home/.ecryptfs/secretuser/.Private/../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]
Oct  9 06:05:19 zhadum ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Error attempting to unwrap passphrase from file [/home/.ecryptfs/secretuser/.Private/../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]; rc = [-5]
Oct  9 06:05:21 zhadum wpa_supplicant[1625]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
```

and also:

```
masteruser@zhadum:/var/log$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/secretuser/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] n
INFO: To recover this directory, you MUST have your original MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: When you first setup your encrypted private directory, you were told to record
INFO: your MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: It should be 32 characters long, consisting of [0-9] and [a-f].
Enter your MOUNT passphrase: byebye secretuser...
```

I guess I am done now. I now go grieving over my dumbassery and then ask another question how to truly remove the 32 GB of *secretuser* from my harddisk - to make sure not to leave even more mess...

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the passphrase you used when you created the encrypted user. **That passphrase is not your password**  ! Once you have found it, assuming you kept it, run :

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

see more [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I did as suggested in the link you gave. Now I have something mounted in tmp but when I change to it, I see all cryptic files and directories like `-rw-------  1 secretuser secretuser  1406 Jul 20 22:49 ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXY7udVWRxM.T-Q7zrsGtqZT23BeaSWl8nYLnAY4SWzDYOrL4qvZhrIoZ0e4Yp4FMUXCcwf1KNUkZHw-` and even `cat`ing the files gives I/O error. Seems that I have to go with the delete and restore. Pity that. Encryption was obviously one step too secure. I was thinking that the key is stored in some keyring and is automatically unlocked on logon. But seemingly... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Maybe you should just make a full backup of your encrypted files, just in case some one shows up with a solution in the next days. I'm not an expert and I might have miss something. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

You do need either

- the last login passphrase (the one just before you forced a new login passphrase with `sudo`)

  or
- the original mount passphrase created when the encryption was set up.

The `wrapped-passphrase` file holds the mount passphrase for your encrypted home, and is encrypted with your login passphrase. By forcing a new passphrase with sudo, without having the old one or being logged in, your `wrapped-passphrase` file was not decrypted and re-encrypted with the new login passphrase. This is by design to provide real security that any `sudo`-armed user can't bypass.

When you set up your encrypted home with the eCryptFS tool `ecryptfs-migrate-home` it asks you to make a backup copy of the actual mount passphrase, just in case a problem like this comes up (you forget your login passphrase or the `wrapped-passphrase` file is lost or damaged.

Having just the login passphrase from when you first created the user probably won't be useful, unless you also have a copy of the `wrapped-passphrase` file from the same time, using the same login passphrase.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the backup copy. I should have done, yes... Btw. I really wonder why the encrytion does not employ a certificate with passphrase - which everyone interested in encryption at all could handle right away - rather than some special foo that's different to anything else...?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if the Ubuntu installer has the same "make a backup of this mount key" advice, it seems most people set up an encrypted home at install, and not using the migrate-home script. Not sure about certificates, if they're encrypted with a passphrase then is that essentially how the `wrapped-passphrase` file works now? Or like using your pgp/gpg key somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer just to share my insights from this incident:

With an encrypted home directory, don't forget your password **and** your passphrase. You will be lost even when you have other admin users on that machine.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/33732/184228) to a similar question might provide helpful background info for others. It also explains why I can delete *secureuser* and will not encrypt a home directory again.

Together with the experience from [this gem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332810/ubuntu-13-04-does-not-boot-after-update) I really think that encrypting the home partition (and only the home partition) has the best security-to-risk ratio. At least all the other options have proven to be more risk than fun...