# How to remove user with encrypted home directory when password and passphrase are lost

Tags: 14.04, encryption, users

After [this here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682922/encrypted-home-dir-cannot-login-after-sudo-password-reset), I want to remove user *secureuser* whose home directory is encrypted, but password and passphrase are lost. Since the home directory was holding some 30 Gig of data, I want to be sure that the encrypted content will really be gone afterwards. Will a

```
deluser --remove-home secureuser
```

be ok in this situation or is there anything special to care for?

Background: I do not want to end up in a situation where I have the user removed and some zombie 30 Gig occupying the SSD which cannot be addressed any more...

Comment: "30 Gig occupying the SSD which cannot be addressed any more" you can always format it ;)

Comment: Formatting the hard disk or at least the `home` partition would require 9 other user accounts to be restored from backup too. Not really the thing you want to spend your weekend with. On the other hand, without the 30 Gig freed, I would not be able to restore the *secretuser* account. Surely a good reason for a downvote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there were no useful hints or caveats from the community, I just jumped into cold water and did a

```
sudo deluser --remove-home secureuser
```

Just in case anyone else might share my hesitation: It worked fine and released the 30 Gig from the file system. The `deluser` also removed the group `secureuser` and all the references in group assignments.